# Condition should also check amount of rows

Tags: prometheus, grafana, alert

I have following setting of alert (**Grafana v9.2.3**):
[image]

[image]

[image]

And result is okay:

[image]

I want to have same result but condition should also check amount of rows. If more than 5 - send result as alert (in example only 3 rows but still sends alert).

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

You can use promQL query for this, no need for Grafana aggregation.

If you want to just check that there are 5 or more metrics:

```
count(srv{val="10"}) >= 5
```

If you want to check both average and number of metrics:

```
avg(srv{val="10"}) > 1000 and count(srv{val="10"}) >= 5
```

Comment: Does not work. It is the new alert system.Result for count(srv{val="10"}) results 1

Comment: @OkyDokyman, please clarify then what `srv{val="10"}` returns (you can see it in explore) and what conditions should trigger alert.